# How do I correctly filter by a specific product attribute (Brand in this case) in Woocommerce backend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to be upfront and say I haven't coded in around 10 years. My knowledge is close to zero coding PHP but being a IT professional I am not a "complete" idiot.

In the product list of Woocommerce (backend) I want to have a Brand filter.
I made a product attribute called "Brand". With the help of a few websites I compiled this bit of code in my Functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_filters', 'Filter_chosen_attributes' );
 
function Filter_chosen_attributes( $output ) {
   
  global $wp_query;
 
  $output .= wc_product_dropdown_categories( array(
   'show_option_none' => 'Filter by product attributes',
   'taxonomy' => 'product_attributes',
   'name' => 'product_attributes',
   'selected' => isset( $wp_query->chosen_attributes['product_attributes'] ) ? $wp_query->chosen_attributes['product_attributes'] : '',
  ) );
   
  return $output;
}
```

I don't know how to specify that I want to filter the brand product attribute.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this [tutorial](https://thestizmedia.com/custom-post-type-filter-admin-custom-taxonomy/) you could use something like this (place the code inside functions.php)

```
/**
 * Display a custom taxonomy dropdown in admin
 * @author Mike Hemberger
 * @link http://thestizmedia.com/custom-post-type-filter-admin-custom-taxonomy/
 */
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'tsm_filter_post_type_by_taxonomy');
function tsm_filter_post_type_by_taxonomy() {
    global $typenow;
    $post_type = 'product'; // change to your post type
    $taxonomy  = 'product_brand'; // change to your taxonomy
    if ($typenow == $post_type) {
        $selected      = isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) ? $_GET[$taxonomy] : '';
        $info_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
        wp_dropdown_categories(array(
            'show_option_all' => sprintf( __( 'Show all %s', 'textdomain' ), $info_taxonomy->label ),
            'taxonomy'        => $taxonomy,
            'name'            => $taxonomy,
            'orderby'         => 'name',
            'selected'        => $selected,
            'show_count'      => true,
            'hide_empty'      => true,
        ));
    };
}
/**
 * Filter posts by taxonomy in admin
 * @author  Mike Hemberger
 * @link http://thestizmedia.com/custom-post-type-filter-admin-custom-taxonomy/
 */
add_filter('parse_query', 'tsm_convert_id_to_term_in_query');
function tsm_convert_id_to_term_in_query($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $post_type = 'product'; // change to your post type
    $taxonomy  = 'product_brand'; // change to your taxonomy
    $q_vars    = &$query->query_vars;
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($q_vars['post_type']) && $q_vars['post_type'] == $post_type && isset($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && is_numeric($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && $q_vars[$taxonomy] != 0 ) {
        $term = get_term_by('id', $q_vars[$taxonomy], $taxonomy);
        $q_vars[$taxonomy] = $term->slug;
    }
}
```

to find the correct Taxonomy you have to look in the URL for the GET parameter taxonomy see example below the bolt part is the correct taxonomy

yourdomain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=**product_brand**&post_type=product

Comment: You are a godsend! Thank you I managed to make it work!